# Fixing an images and names locations

Tags: html, css

I was trying to code a website but the image and the name (Administracija) are appearing on the left side but they should be appearing where the search bar is.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
:root {
  --main-color: #DD2F6E;
  --color-dark: #1D2231;
  --text-grey: #8390A2;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 345px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--main-color);
}

.sidebar-brand {
  height: 90px;
  padding: 1rem 0rem 1rem 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-brand span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.sidebar-menu li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.sidebar-menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.sidebar-menu a.active {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.sidebar-menu a span:first-child {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.main-content {
  margin-left: 345px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.search-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.search-wrapper span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.search-wrapper input {
  height: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.user-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-wrapper img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.user-wrapper small {
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--text-grey);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bibliotekos administracija</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-brand">
      <h2><span class="lab la-accusoft"></span> Biblioteka</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="active"><span class="las la-home"></span>
                <span>Pradžia</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><span class="las la-clipboard"></span>
                <span>Knygų sąrašas</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><span class="las la-book"></span>
                <span>Paimtos knygos</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <header>
      <h2>
        <label for="">
                    <span class="las la-bars" ></span>
                </label> Pradžia
      </h2>

      <div class="search-wrapper">
        <span class="las la-search"></span>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search here" />


      </div>

    </header>

    <div class="user-wrapper">

      <img src="img/among.jpg" width="40px" height="40px" alt="">
      <div>
        <h4>Administracija</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

    <main>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-single">
          <div>
            <h1>0</h1>
            <span>Knygų</span>

          </div>
          <div>
            <span class="las la-books"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </main>

  </div>


</body>


</html>
```

So I was watching a video on how to make a admin website and in that video there's a step where the admin's name and picture should appear on the top right corner where right now my search bar is, but it doesn't do that it just stays on the left side anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your header then should be:

```
<header>
    <h2>
        <label for="">
            <span class="las la-bars" ></span>
        </label>
        Pradžia
    </h2>
    
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <span class="las la-search"></span>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search here"/>
    </div>

    <div class="user-wrapper">

        <img src="img/among.jpg" width="40px" height="40px" alt="">
        <div>
            <h4>Administracija</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I'd recommend learning the basics of HTML, specifically layout building before starting building complex projects, since the lack of the essential knowledge can potentially bring a lot of complexity and misunderstanding.